# Is it possible to put an image from a URL in a imagebutton in android?

Tags: android

What I want to do is a database listview
With a small image button and text on the right side,
Then I want the small image to change with a URL given by
a text file but I am stuck and the 2-hour rule is up

For(file length)
So URL is [www.site.com/images/(i++).png](http://www.site.com/images/(i++).png)

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do  is. Impossible
For all reasons.

Comment: Probably not impossible. Could you try explaining the question a little more thoroughly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do is definitely possible, however, you will need to manually fetch the image and set it on the ImageButton.

Here is a little method you can use to fetch an image:

```
private Bitmap fetchImage( String urlstr )
{
    try
    {
        URL url;
        url = new URL( urlstr );

        HttpURLConnection c = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
        c.setDoInput( true );
        c.connect();
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
        Bitmap img;
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );
        return img;
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException e )
    {
        Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage passed invalid URL: " + urlstr );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage IO exception: " + e );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of course, you will want to wrap this method in a thread (Using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with SDK 1.5 or [UserTask](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/UserTask.java) in SDK pre 1.5), then simply call:

```
myImageButton.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
```

I think this has answered your question, if not please elaborate further.

Comment: If your like me and your list is fairly long and images potentially large the line "img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );" will get you into OOM (Out of Memory) land very quickly. Luckily SO has pleeenty of answers for that too. Just something to look out for. gl!

Answer (score 2):

The fetchImage code above fails with
**DEBUG/skia(xxxx): --- decoder->decode returned false**
if it is called repeatedly.
(There are several discussions of this already on StackOverflow.com)

It's not a crash or catchable error but returns a null bitmap.

This alternate fetchImage works (can anyone say why?):

```
private Bitmap fetchImage(String urlstr){
    InputStream is= null;
    Bitmap bm= null;
    try{
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(urlstr);//bitmapUrl.toURI());
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
    }catch ( MalformedURLException e ){
        Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage passed invalid URL: " + urlstr );
    }catch ( IOException e ){
        Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage IO exception: " + e );
    }finally{
        if(is!=null)try{
            is.close();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
    return bm;
}
```