# Does ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri) work with remote files?

Tags: android

Is it possible to load an image from a remote server using ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri)?

Comment: You didn't try it yet? I've been using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844972/is-it-possible-to-put-an-image-from-a-url-in-a-imagebutton-in-android) approach. EDIT: [Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4724.htm)'s another cool example.

Comment: By the way, it's `ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri)` (`URI` != `Uri`) -- big difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is no! It can't.

You could use ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri) for instance if the uri contains a reference to a local file.
Eg: file:///sdcard/images/thumb.png

Answer (score 7):

To load an image from a directory, it should be converted to a `Drawable` first. Here is a piece of code which can help:

```
File file = new File ("/sdcard/1.jpg");

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Be warned that there is another method for `ImageView` called `setImageURI(URI uri)`. This method is used to load external files; it doesn't work with the type `File`. **For example, this code won't work:**

```
File file = new File ("/sdcard/1.jpg");

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Thanks to Martin Wibbels for [this post](http://mwibbels.blogspot.com/2010/11/imageviewsetimageuri-does-not-work-for.html).

Comment: That last code sample actually does work for me (API level 15 or so). Maybe that's a new thing. But also note that the argument to `setImageURI()` is a `Uri`, not a `URI`.