# Android: ImageSwitcher

Tags: android

How do I use the imageswithcer to load picture from my website,, 
I mean, do I need to send images as binary? 
or can I use Imageswitcher on URls on the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use URIs to fetch remote images.  You need to fetch the image and store it locally.  One convenient way is to use the Drawable.createFromStream method.  For some good links, see the answer from Macarse here: [Does ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri) work with remote files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076457/does-imageview-setimageuriuri-uri-work-with-remote-files)

Comment: I have all this done, but unlike a BaseAdapter there is no notifyDataSetChanged function to have it update when the async call comes back. Ideas on how to get the ImageSwitcher to update/refresh when the image comes back?