# ImageView with Russian web URL

Tags: java, android, imageview

ImageView dont show Image with URL with Russian letters.
Tried URLEncode, but still dont work/ In project was used Fresco

```
 String norm = "http://www.rts-tender.ru/Portals/0/EasyDNNNews/1523/1523риадагестан.jpg";

 for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){ 
try { 
          s = s.replace(""+((char)('а'+j)),""+URLEncoder.encode(""+  ((char)‌​('а'+j)),encoding)); 
} 
  catch (Exception e) { 
     e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
}

 viewHolder.imagePreview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(norm));
```

Comment: I assume your *question* is something like _how to handle russian letters in an URI_. What happens exactly? How did you try to use URLEncode?

Comment: I can show Images with english URL. But russian, even with URLEncode doesnt work

Comment: for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
            try {
                s = s.replace(""+((char)('а'+j)),""+URLEncoder.encode(""+((char)('а'+j)),encoding));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: Please update your question to contain this information (and format it as code, such that people can read it).

Comment: Your url does not work to begin with. Try it in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `ImageView` does not support remote content. You need to download the image, or use Glide or Picasso to do that for you.

> In me project was used Fresco, excuse me, i forgot.

Then it smells like Fresco's bug as image's source is completely irrelevant for ImageView.

Here's more useful link in this case:https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues

Comment: I can show Images with english URL. But russian, even with URLEncode doesnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076457/does-imageview-setimageuriuri-uri-work-with-remote-files

Comment: In me project was used Fresco, excuse me, i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String norm = "http://www.rtstender.ru/Portals/0/EasyDNNNews/1523/1523риадагестан.jpg";
URLEncoder.encode(norm, HTTP.UTF-8);
viewHolder.imagePreview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(norm));
```